# Nextjs not correctly load GetStaticProps and not return props to page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I can't call `getStaticProps` function in my Next.js/React project. I want to load `getStaticProps` when the page path changes to `/blog` so in my `pages/blogs`

```
type BlogStaticInputs = {
    blogs: BlogsType[]
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    console.log('hello')
    const blogs = getAllBlogs(['date', 'slug', 'title'])

    return {
        props: { blogs }
    }
}

export const Index = ({ blogs }: BlogStaticInputs) => {
    return <Blogs blogs={blogs} />
}

export default Index
```

and my `BlogType` is

```
export type BlogType = {
    date?: string
    slug: string
    title: string
}
```

And I cannot see `console.log('hello')` in my console so I believe the `getStaticProps` is not working currently.

In my `_app.tsx` - and I think this is correctly loading props and components.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

    return (
        <>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

And my `getAllBlogs` looks like this

```
export function getAllBlogs(fields: string[] = []): BlogItems[] {
    console.log('I am getting blogs now...')
    const slugs = getBlogSlugs()
    const posts = slugs
        .map((slug) => getBlogBySlug(slug, fields))
        // sort posts by date in descending order
        .sort((post1, post2) => (post1.date > post2.date ? -1 : 1))
    return posts
}
```

and supporting functions are these.

```
export function getBlogSlugs(): string[] {
    return fs.readdirSync(POSTS_PATH)
}

type BlogItems = {
    [key: string]: string
}

export function getBlogBySlug(slug: string, fields: string[] = []): BlogItems {
    const realSlug = slug.replace(/\.mdx$/, '')
    const fullPath = join(POSTS_PATH, `${realSlug}.mdx`)
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8')
    const { data, content } = matter(fileContents)

    const items: BlogItems = {}

    // Ensure only the minimal needed data is exposed
    fields.forEach((field) => {
        if (field === 'slug') {
            items[field] = realSlug
        }
        if (field === 'content') {
            items[field] = content
        }
        if (data[field]) {
            items[field] = data[field]
        }
    })

    return items
}
```

and supporting function to get blogs directory path

```
export const POSTS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'blogs')
```

I think `getAllBlogs` function is not yet called since I cannot see `console.log('I am getting blogs now...')`.

Comment: How getAllBlogs function look like?

Comment: I added `getAllBlog` function! I tried to console.log(blogs) in my `export const Index` function before calling `return <Blogs blogs={blogs} />, the param blogs are still empty

Comment: Make sure of the following: 1) Ensure `getStaticProps` is exported from a page component (component under the `pages` folder); 2) Check the terminal where you started the dev server for any `console.log`s you have inside `getStaticProps` - `getStaticProps` runs on the server so these won't appear in the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting in with a more strongly typed solution, I did notice that your `BlogType` type is renamed `BlogTypes` in the pages/index.tsx file? Is the `s` at the end referencing the same type as `BlogType`?

```
// BlogType
export type BlogType = {
    date?: string
    slug: string
    title: string
}

// versus

// In your Index (pages/index.tsx) file
type BlogStaticInputs = {
    blogs: BlogsType[]
}
```

At any rate, I'll be using the `BlogType` type that is defined above going forward.

First, define this in a types directory in your root or inside of the src directory if you're using the `src` setup.

```
/**
 * @type {ParsedUrlQuery}
 * @description url query params
 */
export type ParsedUrlQuery<T = string, N = NodeJS.Dict<T | T[]>> = N;
```

I've done something similar, and I think I see the issue. Just adding a few bonus tips for working with Next+TypeScript (my specialization for over a year was Nextjs + headless wordpress builds)

The `ParsedUrlQuery` type can be used with `GetStaticProps`, `GetStaticPaths`, and `GetServerSideProps`.

This is a reusable and useful component for these kinds of situations. I wrote it using Tailwindcss as my styles framework so if you're using something else simply replace the content of `className`

```
import { FC } from "react";

const DataInspector: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div
      lang='json'
      className='font-gothamLight container max-w-7xl break-normal'>
      <pre className='container flex-col mx-auto text-[12px] bg-[#151515] text-yellow-400 w-8xl max-w-8xl overflow-x-hidden'>
        {JSON.stringify(children, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataInspector;
```

Once that is defined, give this a try with `GetStaticProps` -- it will error if you don't have the established types being passed correctly. You will also be able to see the inferred types returned to the client as follows:

```
import type {
  GetStaticPropsContext,
  GetStaticPropsResult,
  InferGetStaticPropsType
} from "next";
// update import paths below accordingly
import type { ParsedUrlQuery } from "@/types/index";
import type { BlogType } from "@/types/blog-type";
import DataInspector from "@/components/data-inspector";

type BlogStaticInputs = {
    blogs: BlogType[]
}

// try hovering over `blogs` -- you'll notice it's strongly typed
export default function Index<T extends typeof getStaticProps>({
  blogs
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<T>) {
    const tempErrObj = { error: new Error(`[Blogs data handling error]: ${blogs}`).message };
    return (
    <>
      {blogs && blogs.length > 0 
        ? <Blogs blogs={blogs} /> 
        : <DataInspector>{blogs ? blogs : tempErrObj}</DataInspector>
      }
    </>
   );
}

export const getStaticProps = async (
  ctx: GetStaticPropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery>
): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<BlogStaticInput>> => {

   const blogs = getAllBlogs(['date', 'slug', 'title']);

    return {
        props: { blogs }
    };
}
```